# CString assignment error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c-strings

Can someone explain why strY assignment won't compile? I thought that the compiler might have replaced the assignment with a constructor but strZ compiles, as does strX.

```
unsigned char szArr[]{ 0xD7, 0x53, 0xBF, 0xE7};

CString strX;
strX = szArr;
CString strY = szArr;
// no suitable constructor exists to convert unsigned char[4] to ...
CString strZ(szArr);
```

Comment: For starters you should include the full error message in the question and secondly you should read the compiler messages yourself.

Comment: This works fine for me with Visual Studio 2015. What compiler flags are you using? What's the full error message? Is this a `const` issue?

Comment: By any chance do you have "Use Unicode Character Set" for your project settings (General page)?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Did read it and included the bulk of in in the comment. here's the full text: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "unsigned char [33]" to "ATL::CStringT<wchar_t, StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t, ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>" StringTest e:\Projects\Test\StringTest\StringTest\StringTest.cpp

Comment: Yes, well that explains it. Replace `unsigned char` with `const TCHAR`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's a default console app, I made no project setting changes.

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks. My actual question is what is different in the three ways the strings are being set? Why is only strY an error?

Comment: I feel like many people here not aware that there is `CString::operator=(const unsigned char*); [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300557(v=vs.60).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further reading/playing it seems strZ is using this constructor:

```
CSTRING_EXPLICIT CStringT(_In_z_ const unsigned char* pszSrc) :
    CThisSimpleString( StringTraits::GetDefaultManager() )
```

And that works because it's explicitly called

strX is using the default constructor then assignment operator:

```
CStringT& operator=(_In_opt_z_ const unsigned char* pszSrc)
```

And thanks to ChristopherOicles comment:

When _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS is defined, all CString constructors that take a single parameter are compiled with the explicit keyword, which prevents implicit conversions of input arguments.

So without _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS defined strY will use the same constructor as strZ. The stub for a Windows console app has this defined in stdafx.h

Comment: Do you have `#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS` in your `stdafx.h`?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles That's it! Defined by default in a non-empty project. Add this as an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Could your update your own answer with the new info?  I'm fine with that.